# Microsoft Graph Client SDK vs. Requesting JSONs

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I know that the query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages 
Corresponds to:
GraphClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync()

I am trying to replicate the following requests in Microsoft Graph Client SDK :

1. Get All Categories 
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/masterCategories
   Corresponding Graph client query: ??
2. Get All messages that contain certain words in their subject 
   The link will be similar to this
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="hello world"
   Corresponding Graph Client : ??
3. Update each of these messages with a category
   ?

The documentation only gives 2 examples, where could i find a list of examples/reading material on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The SDK is generated for the production endpoint (v1.0), so you will have to make a [custom request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library) for beta APIs
2. `List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
   {
        new QueryOption("$search", "hello world")
   };
   var filteredMessages = await 
   graphClient.Me.Messages.Request(options).GetAsync();`
3. This also requires using custom requests since this is beta functionality.

We appreciate your feedback about our docs and how to use the SDK. We have some [additional reference](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/tree/dev/docs) in the repo and are continuing to examine options for improving our SDK docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation points, I had to post an answer instead of a comment. 
Thanks user8608110 for your help. Unfortunately, I can't use graph explorer because I'm not an admin.  I think I have my patch request setup correctly, but I keep getting an "Empty Payload" error.

I thought stackoverflow was for us to help each other not delete the post of people trying to get help.

Comment: Hi, I do not think you have to be an admin to use patch requests. You can select the non admin permissions. Perhaps you are trying to patch an admin request? What is your code?

Comment: I figured the code out.  Thank you again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291693/empty-payload-json-content-expected-error-calling-microsoft-graph