# How to update a Mail Message Category. Was getting “Empty Payload. JSON content expected” error calling Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have seen a few questions posted with this same problem. I think I have all the pieces, but I am still getting the "Empty Payload" error. Does anyone see what is missing?

I want to update the category of some mail messages.  I am using the beta endpoint because of this post: [Microsoft Graph Client SDK vs. Requesting JSONs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072912/microsoft-graph-client-sdk-vs-requesting-jsons/49291142#49291142)

Here is my code:

```
public async void UpdateMailCategory(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string messageId, string inbox)
{

    string newCategory = @"{'categories': ['Processed']}";

    try
    {
        // Get the request URL for adding a page. 
        string requestUrl = graphClient
            .Users[inbox]
            .Messages[messageId]
            .Request()
            .RequestUrl;

        HttpRequestMessage hrm =
            new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl);
        hrm.Content =
            new StringContent(newCategory, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
        await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider
            .AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

        // Send the request and get the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response =
            await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
    }
    catch (ServiceException Servex)
    {
        throw Servex;
    }
}
```

When I look at the `hrm.content`, it shows this:

```
{ System.Net.Http.StringContent }
Headers:
{
    Content - Type : application / json;charset = utf - 8
    Content - Length : 35
}
```

Comment: `newCategory` is already a json string. You don't need to serialize it again. You simply pass it to StringContent

Comment: Thank you!  That worked. It seems so simple, and I am learning every day.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Graph Client SDK is a rather roundabout way which is more likely going to cause you headaches than anything else. It also leads to more complicated code than necessary.

The SDK includes everything you need for the entire request. With the exception of an edge case, you should never need to deal with the `HttpProvider` or manage `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` instances.

The following will accomplish the same thing (setting the `Categories` property of a message) with a lot less complexity:

```cs
public async void UpdateMailCategory(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string messageId, string inbox)
{
    try
    {
        await graphClient
            .Users[inbox]
            .Messages[messageId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(new Message()
            {
                Categories = new List<string>() { "Processed" }
            });
    }
    catch (ServiceException Servex)
    {
        throw Servex;
    }
}
```

You also shouldn't use the `/beta` version for this operation as it *is* supported by the `/v1.0` version. You should only need to leverage the `/beta` version to manage the user's Categories since this *isn't* generally available yet.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried to find how to do this in some documentation somewhere and I never could.  I even have some engineers from MS working directly on a case with me and they could not find the documentation for it.  I appreciate this soo much!

Comment: Glad to help. If you could mark this as answered, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I need two more reputation points, then I will mark all the answers you've helped me with as answered.